# Can a character with Brawn 5 use a Heavy Repeating Blaster without the tripod?

Tags: star-wars-edge-of-the-empire

Can a character with a Brawn of 5 use a Heavy Repeating Blaster (page 162 of *Edge of the Empire*) without the tripod?

The Heavy Repeating Blaster has a Cumbersome 5 rating, but is described as using a tripod.

Answer (score 4):

## Yes

The Heavy Repeating Blaster comes with a built-in Tripod (page 162):

> Heavy repeaters are far too unwieldy to fire effectively
> without a tripod, unless the bearer has truly
> remarkable strength [...] The cost of
> the weapon includes a tripod such as the one found
> on page 193.

The Tripod's base modifiers (page 193) state:

> Decrease weapon's Cumbersome
> rating by 3 when set up. May not move the weapon
> (except to pivot) once tripod is set up.

Therefore, when using a Tripod, the Heavy Repeating Blaster would only have a Cumbersome 2 rating. When using the Heavy Repeating Blaster without a Tripod, its Cumbersome 5 rating is unchanged.

A Brawn 5 Character may use a Heavy Repeating Blaster without penalty.